# What is the best way to send Image from Base64 by email

Tags: android, email, base64, jpeg

I store photos in SqLite base in Base64 format.

And I need to send this pictures throw email.

For emailing I use Intent.ACTION_SEND.

It is a lot of manuals, how to add File throw Uri to email:

```
ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();

for(String address: pack.getPhotoFileNames()){
   uris.add(Uri.parse("file://"+address));
}
emailIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);

emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
```

like this.

But in this case I need to create File, save it on disk, store Uri to this file, delete file after sending, etc.

So, what is the shortest way to send JPEG created from Base64 (or Bitmap) throw email?

Or: how can I put JPEG files in email without creating temporary files, just from Base64?

Comment: you send an image in Base64 format should the client be able to show you the content ? I think it will show the string. Am I wrong?

Comment: You will need to provide a decoded image file uri.

Comment: blackbelt, system must put JPEG file to email.

Comment: where do you read it?

Comment: blackbelt, where do I read what?

Comment: I see your problem now. Your current procedure is forcing you to create temporary file for you to send it, and you want to avoid that?

Comment: Marko Lazic, yes You are right. I try to find simplest way.

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly for more clarity. Either way it's a good question

Comment: system must put JPEG file to email. this sentence does not make sense to me